# How to make Office Add-in (Apps for Office) in Visual Studio to open a template file instead of a new workbook?

Tags: office-js

Our office add-in is expecting some data to be available in the document before it can process the requests. When running Apps for Office project template in Visual Studio, is there any way to open up a document template instead of opening a blank document (word or excel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your template document to the "Manifest" project, and then set the Start Document property to point at your file, rather than a "New Excel Workbook" (or what new file type it's set to).

It looks like http://simonjaeger.com/apps-for-office-use-a-custom-start-document/ describes the step-by-step process.  Including two of the pictures from his site below, see the blog post itself for the text content if the pictures don't guide you all the way there.

**Add/include file to manifest solution:**

[image: Add/include file to manifest solution]

**Set start document**

[image: Set start document]

Comment: The document is loading after setting the template as the Start Document. But somehow, the add-in is not getting loaded in the template. But if I change to `[New Excel Workbook]`, the add-in is loading fine. I am using VS 2015. Am I missing anything?

Comment: We don't pre-insert the Add-in into an existing document. Instead you need to manually add it once via Insert -> My Add-ins dropdown, and the Developer group.  Then save the document, and you'll be good from there on out.